# "Error: unsupported relocation against <register>" error with inline PPC assembly code in .c file

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, powerpc

I have below inline assembly code. But when i try to compile it, It throws error mentioned after the code snippet.

```
unsigned int func(void)
{
  __asm__ ("mfspr r3, svr;");
}
```

Below are the errors.

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:3349: Error: unsupported relocation against r3
{standard input}:3349: Error: unsupported relocation against svr
{standard input}:3375: Error: unsupported relocation against r3
{standard input}:3375: Error: unsupported relocation against svr
{standard input}:3510: Error: unsupported relocation against r3
{standard input}:3510: Error: unsupported relocation against svr
{standard input}:3517: Error: unsupported relocation against r3
{standard input}:3517: Error: unsupported relocation against svr
```

Can anyone help me fixing these?

Answer (score 3):

You should specify inputs and outputs explicitly.  As written, your ASM block may be optimized out!

```
unsigned int func(void)
{
    unsigned x;
    __asm__("mfspr %0, svr" : "=b"(x));
    return x;
}
```

The compiler is smart enough to figure out that the register should be `r3`.  (That's one of the compiler's main jobs: register allocation to minimize extra moves.)

If you leave out the output specification, and then compile with optimization enabled, you may find that your function is empty, without the `mfspr` opcode anywhere to be found.

Comment: @vimalprathap: Maybe `svr` isn't defined.  Use the numeric version.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I have a similar error in my build, albeit for system call swapcontext, please do kindly look into it as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785554/error-in-assembler-unsupported-relocation-against-nr-swapcontext

Answer (score 2):

Apparently gas has no built-in support for these registers. In order to use those you should either define them yourself or use their indexes explicitly like:

```
mfspr 3, <some_index_here>
```

Alternatively you could include: [ppc_asm.tmpl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/ppc/kernel/ppc_asm.tmpl?v=2.0.40).

If your core is an [e500](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/E500CORERM.pdf) then svr index would be 1023.

Comment: @vimalprathap Yes. See the e500mc reference manual: http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/E500MCRM.pdf

Answer (score 1):

At least some of the errors will go away if you pass `-mregnames` option to the assembler. (`-Wa,-mregnames`). gas 2.19 supports the following symbolic register names for PPC (from binutils-2.19/gas/config/tc-ppc.c):

```
/* List of registers that are pre-defined:

   Each general register has predefined names of the form:
   1. r<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.
   2. r.<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.

   Each floating point register has predefined names of the form:
   1. f<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.
   2. f.<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.

   Each vector unit register has predefined names of the form:
   1. v<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.
   2. v.<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.

   Each condition register has predefined names of the form:
   1. cr<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.
   2. cr.<reg_num> which has the value <reg_num>.

   There are individual registers as well:
   sp or r.sp     has the value 1
   rtoc or r.toc  has the value 2
   fpscr          has the value 0
   xer            has the value 1
   lr             has the value 8
   ctr            has the value 9
   pmr            has the value 0
   dar            has the value 19
   dsisr          has the value 18
   dec            has the value 22
   sdr1           has the value 25
   srr0           has the value 26
   srr1           has the value 27

   The table is sorted. Suitable for searching by a binary search.  */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the helpful error message that gas emits when it is trying to say that it doesn't know that "r3" and "svr" are the names of registers. gas expects numbers instead of register names for register operands. You'd get similar error messages if you tried

```
__asm__ ("mfspr foo, fum;");
```

In other words, gas is interpreting the register names as arbitrary symbols.